# Adding View from Different ViewModel to MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a MainWindow in which i load all my views into ItemControls which has canvas.

In my MainWindowViewModel, i can able to add a View using ObservableCollection binded to ItemControl.

But now i also want to add View to the MainWindow from the ViewModel of a different View which is already in MainWindow.

How can i do this. I was trying a lot from the past 5 hrs and  failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Prism's [region](http://www.google.com/search?q=prism%20regions) infrastructure. You could either use that or create your own equivalent.

Comment: i am not interested in using any external dlls